# Nuxt & Firebase - IE 11 (Object doesn't support property or method 'values')

Tags: firebase, vue.js, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, nuxt.js

I'm having trouble getting Nuxt and babel when trying to polyfill firebase for IE11. I'm not sure what I am missing.

`useBuiltIns: "usage"` IE11 returns an error of `Object doesn't support property or method 'values'`

When `useBuiltIns: "entry"` IE11 returns an error of `Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'`

nuxt.config.js

```
babel: {
    presets({ envName }) {
      const envTargets = {
        client: {
          browsers: ["last 2 versions"],
          ie: 11
        },
        server: {
          node: "current"
        },
      }
      return [
        [
          "@nuxt/babel-preset-app",
          {
            useBuiltIns: "usage",
            polyfills: ['es6.array.iterator', 'es6.promise', 'es6.object.assign', 'es7.object.values', 'es7.promise.finally'],
            targets: envTargets[envName]
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.10.2",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.15.0",
    "core-js": "2.6.11",
    "firebase": "^7.15.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.12.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-select": "^3.10.3"
  },
```

Comment: You could try to add the `core-js/stable` and `cross-fetch/polyfill` suggested in the [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk#polyfills) about polyfills. They're suggested to be used in IE 11. Besides, you could refer to [this article](https://itnext.io/how-to-create-a-ssr-serverless-app-with-firebase-nuxt-js-in-an-hour-6e6e03d0b3b8) about how to use firebase and Nuxt.js. It shows how to support old browsers using babel in part 5.

Comment: I've tried importing those packages in via the nuxt plugins (with updating core-js to v3 as the firebase docs suggest) but I still have the same issue. Thanks for sharing the article but it refers to nuxt v1, and they have changed the way babel is used/declared in nuxt v2

Comment: Which line and which file does the error point to? For the second issue, I found a [similar thread](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/93) in github. There's a [solution](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/93#issuecomment-348986778) below you could refer to: (1) adding 'babel-polyfill' to vendors in nuxt.config.js; (2) setting `useBuiltins` to `true` to avoid double polyfillings.

Comment: Yeah I've already looked at this, again it's using nuxt v1 so the babel config is a little different in [v2](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#babel). I've tried to amend it to work with v2 config but it doesn't seem to work. If you have any ideas that would be great, thanks again

Comment: Could you please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You could show your sample using some online code editors like [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/). So that we can have a better understading of the issue and can have a test on our end. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Firebase has its own [polyfill package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/polyfill) included in the sdk.

You need to import that package by:

1. Creating `/plugins/polyfills.js` containing:

```js
import '@firebase/polyfill';
```

You can, instead, import in that file the polyfills you think you need individually, so the final bundle will be smaller. Example:

```js
import '@firebase/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/features/object/values';
```

2. Add to your `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
plugins: [
  { src: '~plugins/polyfills', mode: 'client' },
],
```

Comment: firebase states in the package readme: "This package is not intended for direct usage, and should only be used via the officially supported firebase package."